# Ansible - how to copy module with diff enabled show content AND mode differences?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to use the **template** and **copy** module in **check_mode** to see the differences between my repository and the target file. I have mode and ownership defined for every file.

The behavior I get is:

- If there is a *content* difference and *mode* difference - only *content* difference is shown
- If the content is the same, but *mode* differs, only mode difference is shown.

The behavior I want is:

- If there is a *content* difference and the *mode* difference - show both content diff and mode diff